# URL routing in PHP (MVC)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am building a custom MVC project and I have a base folder `/mvc` that contains `.htaccess` and `routes.php` files and that is placed in `C:\xampp\htdocs` root folder. Here are my files:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!routes\.php).+)$ /mvc/routes.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\routes.php**

```
<?php
# Routing logic goes here...
```

## Problem

I'd like to move `routes.php` into `mvc/app` folder, hence I changed this line in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^((?!routes\.php).+)$ /mvc/routes.php [L]
```

to this line:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!routes\.php).+)$ /mvc/app/routes.php [L]
```

**But that does not seem to work!** I get a 500 error. What am I doing here? I'd like to redirect ALL requests (including any `.php` or other file requests, excluding images) to `mvc/app/routes.php`, which will handle the HTTP requests and direct them to the appropriate controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|css|gif|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!app/routes\.php).+)$ /mvc/app/routes.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Update: all I had to do is change `^((?!mvc/app/routes\.php).+)$` to `^((?!app/routes\.php).+)$`. `mvc/` is not needed here, because `.htaccess` is already inside `mvc/` folder! Thanks!